# Missing xmlns namespace attribute for 'feed' element in ATOM with ASP.Net Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, atom-feed

I am developing a ASP.Net Web API project.

There is a requirement to return a ATOM feed on changes to resources in the application.

I have the feed all working but for some reason my feed element is omitting the 'xmlns' element which describes the XML as an ATOM feed.

The desired result is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <title type="text">My Feed</title>
    <id>uuid:ff389357-aaab-4814-8916-b8fff325e6bb;id=22</id>
    <updated>2013-04-11T16:15:10Z</updated>
    <entry>
      <id>uuid:ff389357-aaab-4814-8916-b8fff325e6bb;id=23</id>
      <title type="text">Data.Parliament Resource 1</title>
      <updated>2013-04-11T16:15:10Z</updated>
      <author>
        <name>Parliament System X</name>
      </author>
     </entry>
  </feed>
```

But my feed looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <feed>
    <title type="text">My Feed</title>
    <id>uuid:ff389357-aaab-4814-8916-b8fff325e6bb;id=22</id>
    <updated>2013-04-11T16:15:10Z</updated>
    <entry>
      <id>uuid:ff389357-aaab-4814-8916-b8fff325e6bb;id=23</id>
      <title type="text">Data.Parliament Resource 1</title>
      <updated>2013-04-11T16:15:10Z</updated>
      <author>
        <name>Parliament System X</name>
      </author>
     </entry>
  </feed>
```

Notice the missing 'xmlns' attribute on the 'feed' element.

I've searched high and low to no avail...

**Question:**

**Can anyone explain to me why the 'xmlns' element is missing and how to get it back in there???**

Here is the code for the ATOM media type formatter:

```asp
public class AtomMediaTypeFormatter : BufferedMediaTypeFormatter
{
    private const string AtomMediaType = "application/atom+xml";
    private IFeedHelper _feedService;

    public AtomMediaTypeFormatter(IFeedHelper feedService)
    {
        this._feedService = feedService;
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue(AtomMediaType));
        this.AddQueryStringMapping("format", "atom", AtomMediaType);
    }

    public override bool CanWriteType(Type type)
    {
        return type.Implements<IFeedEntry>() || type.Implements<IFeed>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// DDP is not currently supporting this operation.
    /// </summary>
    public override object ReadFromStream(Type type, Stream readStream, HttpContent content, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the given object value of type <param name="type"></param> to the given stream
    /// </summary>
    public override void WriteToStream(Type type, object value, Stream writeStream, HttpContent content)
    {
        using (writeStream)
        {
            var feed = value as IFeed;
            if (feed != null)
            {
                WriteAtomFeed(feed, writeStream);
            }
            else
            {
                WriteAtomEntry((IFeedEntry)value, writeStream);
            }
        }
    }

    private void WriteAtomFeed(IFeed feed, Stream writeStream)
    {
        var formatter = new Atom10FeedFormatter(_feedService.Syndicate(feed));

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(writeStream))
        {
            formatter.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }

    private void WriteAtomEntry(IFeedEntry feedEntry, Stream writeStream)
    {
        var formatter = new Atom10ItemFormatter(_feedService.Syndicate(feedEntry));

        using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(writeStream))
        {
            formatter.WriteTo(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code for the FeedService.Sydnicate(IFeed) method:

```asp
    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiates and returns a SyndicationFeed using the values of the given IFeed instance
    /// </summary>
    public SyndicationFeed Syndicate(IFeed feed)
    {
        var atomFeed = new SyndicationFeed
        {
            Title = new TextSyndicationContent(feed.Title),
            Id = feed.Id,
            Items = feed.Items.Select(i => Syndicate(i)),
            LastUpdatedTime = feed.LastUpdated
        };

        atomFeed.Links.Add(new SyndicationLink(new Uri(feed.Link.Href), feed.Link.Href, "", "", default(long)));

        return atomFeed;
    }
```

And finally the FeedService.Sydnicate(IFeedEntry):

```asp
    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiates and returns a SyndicationItem using the values of the given IFeedEntry instance
    /// </summary>
    public SyndicationItem Syndicate(IFeedEntry feedEntry)
    {
        var item = new SyndicationItem
        {
            Id = feedEntry.Id,
            Title = new TextSyndicationContent(feedEntry.Title, TextSyndicationContentKind.Plaintext),
            LastUpdatedTime = feedEntry.LastUpdated
        };
        item.Authors.Add(new SyndicationPerson("", feedEntry.Author, ""));
        if (feedEntry.Links != null)
        {
            foreach (var link in feedEntry.Links)
            {
                item.Links.Add(new SyndicationLink(new Uri(link.ToString())));
            }
        }
        return item;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with why the Atom10FeedFormatter is not adding the namespace, but if you don't find a solution I may have an alternative.  I've played around using the ODataMessageWriter to write Atom content.  You can see the source code [here](https://github.com/darrelmiller/HypermediaApiSite/blob/master/HypermediaApiContent/Root/Learning/LearningViewModel.cs) 
and the output (with the namespace) is [here](http://hypermediaapi.com/Learning.atom).

Comment: Thanks for sharing Darrel. I'm not understanding quite how I would utilize that code...two things: 1. what calls the ODataResponse IODataView.CreateView() method and 2. upon returning an instantiated LearningViewModel which formatter kicks in to render the body content?

Comment: @JTech Sorry, I wasn't suggesting you use my approach where the formatter looks for an interface on the viewmodel and calls back into the viewmodel to allow it to render itself.  I was simply suggesting a different library for rendering the Atom feed that you could use in your formatter.